# c# combobox selectedIndex not working when populated by xml file using datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I'm trying to populate two combo boxes from an xml file. Second combobox uses the first combo boxes value to get the values.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxUnit"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource UnitTemplateXML}, XPath=/Units/Unit}"
   DisplayMemberPath="@Name"
   SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedUnitIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbxUnit, Path=SelectedItem}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneTime, XPath=./Template/Name}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTemplateIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ComboBox>
```

They are being populated but the second combobox SelectedIndex isn't working when I use DataContext.
Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: You are changing your data context of the combo box, once you do that your SelectedTemplateIndex would also need to be a property on that same context. You might want to change the item source to bind to the cbxUnit rather than the DataContext.

Comment: I don’t think you want a OneTime binding for itemssource if you’re binding to some detail of a changing selected item in the other combo box. And Jonah is correct about DataContext: Don’t bind it.

Comment: Also the twoway binding in the other itemssource makes no sense: Are you expecting the ComboBox to create a new XML document and replace the resource? That binding is one way by default and couldn’t be twoway if it tried.